# In Django view,How to save array which pass from template via Ajax, to database?

Tags: python, mysql, ajax, django

I create array in JavaScript and send it via Ajax to my view and I can get it in view.Now I want to save  it to my database(mysql) but I get "internal error" from Ajax.I think Ajax when post data to view and Django want to connect MySQL database, connection by ajax was abroted.

this is my template Ajax:

```
var postUrl = "http://localhost:8000/student/{{id}}/student_add_course/";

$('form[name="myForm"]').submit(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:postUrl,
    type: "POST",
    // stock is somthing like this.stock=[[1,12],[2,14],...]
    data: {'stock': stock, 'counter':i,csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);},
     })
});
```

this is view:

```
def student_add_course(request,student_id):
    if request.method=='GET':
        context={'id':student_id , 'form':AddCourseForStudentForm()}
        request.session['ListOfCourses']=[]
        return render(request, 'student/AddCourseForStudentForm.html',context)
    elif request.is_ajax():
        listOFcourses=course_passes.objects.order_by('-id')
        id =listOFcourses[0].id
        counter=int(request.POST.get('counter'))
        for i in range(0,counter):
            selected_course=request.POST.getlist('stock[%d][]'%i)
            //course_passes is my table.

            // evrey thing is good until here but when I want to save it,I get error.
            #a.save()
        return render(request, 'student/add_course.html')
```

What is my code problem and How should I solve it?
Is there better way to do this?

I'm sorry for my bad English.

**Edit**:

Finally I understand my problem is in MySQL side. The value which I want to insert is not correct and I change

```
a=course_passes(id+1,int(selected_course[0]),int(selected_course[1]),int(student_id))
```

to

```
 find_user=user.objects.get(user_code=student_id,task=2)
 a=course_passes(id+1,selected_course[0],selected_course[1],find_user.id)
```

thanks for your comment.

Comment: did you got the id in `student_add_course`

Comment: @rajasimon,Yes I send it with "get" and again in post pass it in URL.

Comment: course.objects.all() should be Course.objects.all()

Comment: @wolendranh,No it's true, "course" is other table but It's for other step and not use here,I clean it in code.thanks

Comment: If you have a Debug True in you settings, you can check response for 500 code from server in Chrome Dev tools. When we will have Traceback it will give more info.